# How to import javascript function with use of ES6 to Polymer 1.0 component?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, es6-modules

I am using Polymer 1.0 and I would like to make my code modular with use of ES6. My idea is to create a few different files with function definitions which I would import to the .html file containing my polymer component definition where I could call them.

I tried to put the import statement into both `created` and `attached` 
polymer functions, but neither works.

Is that what I am trying even possible? If yes, then where should i put my import statement?

Comment: you can do this in polymer 3.0 : https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/es6. I am not sure it's possible in 1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Polymer` v1 imports components was in the html

**Example**

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
```

so you could use webpack now for that and add all your imports in the same file like

```
/* src/index.js */

import './polymer';
import './my-element.html';
```

Put this file as an entry for `webpack` then it will take of all your imports to `generate` a **single HTML file** that you will link in your application.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this in Polymer v1. You need to use a build step to transform the html imports. 
I suggest using webpack and this excellent plugin by Rob Dodson (of the Polymer team) https://robdodson.me/how-to-use-polymer-with-webpack/ that will allow you to do exactly what you want i.e use es6 imports inside the html imports.

Bear in mind that Polymer v1 is now deprecated and you should upgrade to later versions that don't use html imports.